# PHP: PDO (mysql) using bindValue returns wrong result

Tags: php, pdo

The code I've got so far doest return what I need. I can't see what is going wrong here.
With a 'bad' adjustment to the code it gives the right output but I think its better to do it correctly.
And why doesn't it work?

**wrong output: Array ( [L] => L )**

**right output: Array ( [L] => 9 )**

this code give the wrong output:

```
public function getStockByID_SIZE($size, $stockId){
    try {

    $this->_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT :size from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId"); 
    $sth->bindValue(':size', $size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(":stockId", $stockId);

    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {     
        return "Error";  
    }
}
```

Same code but with a (bad) adjustment returns the right code:

```
 $sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT $size from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId");
```

//compared to:

```
 $sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT :size from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId");
 $sth->bindValue(':size', $size); //use of PDO::PARAM_STR doenst matter for outcome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT L from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId");` is the right way.

Your way is just doing `SELECT 'L' from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId` which gives you the result `'L'`.

You can just doing something like below after validate the `$size`,

`$sth=$this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT $size from stock WHERE id_product = :stockId");`

Comment: but L varies, I could use the $size but is that ok?. I'll adjust the op

Comment: @Rob What do you mean $size is validate?

Comment: that $size is validate before it enters the class function . Should it be as well in the class function itself?

Comment: @Rob Then you can use it in your sql.